# SELECT using three tables w/ 1000+ entries

Tags: mysql, select, join

For transaction listing I need to provide the following columns:

- log_out.timestamp
- items.description
- log_out.qty
- category.name
- storage.name
- log_out.dnr ( Representing the users id )

Table structure from `log_out` looks like this:

```
| id | timestamp | storageid | itemid | qty | categoryid | dnr |
|    |           |           |        |     |            |     |
| 1  | ........  |     2     |   23   |  3  |     999    | 123 |
```

As one could guess, I only store the corresponding ID's from other tables in this table. Note: `log_out.id` is the primary key in this table.

To get the the corresponding strings, int's or whatever back, I tried two queries.

#### Approach 1

```
SELECT i.description, c.name, s.name as sname, l.*
FROM items i, categories c, storages s, log_out l
WHERE l.itemid = i.id AND l.storageid = s.id AND l.categoryid = c.id
ORDER BY l.id DESC
```

#### Approach 2

```
SELECT log_out.id, items.description, storages.name, categories.name AS cat, timestamp, dnr, qty
FROM log_out
INNER JOIN items ON log_out.itemid = items.id
INNER JOIN storages ON log_out.storageid = storages.id
INNER JOIN categories ON log_out.categoryid = categories.id
ORDER BY log_out.id DESC
```

They both work fine on my developing machine, which has approx 99 dummy transactions stored in `log_out`. The DB on the main server got something like 1100+ tx stored in the table. And that's where trouble begins. No matter which of these two approaches I run on the main machine, it always returns 0 rows w/o any error ***sigh***.

First I thought, it's because the main machine uses MariaDB instead of MySQL. But after I imported the remote's `log_out` table to my dev-machine, it does the same as the main machine -> return 0 rows w/o error.

You guys got any idea what's going on ?

Comment: Are you shure, the Foreign Keys are set correctly?

Comment: yes. they must be correct, because otherwise the two queries would have failed when querying the dev-setup with 99 tx's.

Comment: Like zambonee, I thought of the data, to be not right.

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood that ! Will dig into this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table has the data then it probably has something to do with `JOIN` and related records in corresponding tables. I would start with `log_out` table and incrementally add the other tables in the `JOIN`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM log_out;

SELECT *
FROM log_out
INNER JOIN items ON log_out.itemid = items.id;

SELECT *
FROM log_out
INNER JOIN items ON log_out.itemid = items.id
INNER JOIN storages ON log_out.storageid = storages.id;

SELECT *
FROM log_out
INNER JOIN items ON log_out.itemid = items.id
INNER JOIN storages ON log_out.storageid = storages.id
INNER JOIN categories ON log_out.categoryid = categories.id;
```

I would execute all the queries one by one and see which one results in 0 records. Additional join in that query would be the one with data discrepancy.

Comment: you sir, deserve a cookie. I guess I should take a break now. It turned out that `category.id` 999 was not set in the main-db. 999 is commonly used in this company for when an item is added to the cart via a handheld scanner.

Answer (score 0):

You're queries look fine to me, which makes me think that it is probably something unexpected with the data. Most likely the ids in your joins are not maintained right (do all of them have a foreign key constraint?). I would dig around the data, like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE id IN (SELECT itemid FROM log_out)`, etc, and seeing if the returns make sense. Sorry I can't offer more advise, but I would be interested in hearing if the problem is in the data itself.

Comment: Alright .. so the data itself *seems* to be correct, as your query returned basically how many items have been used overall in transactions. In my case it returned ~150 on the main table and ~50 on the dev-table. I'm sure what I'm about to say will make me look like a rookie. But I'm not into this foreign keying thing. The way I accomplished things like these until now was to store everything in PHP-Arrays after I fetched each row and pick out the ones I need.

Comment: The next step that I would do is check each `JOIN` from your query one at a time, e.g. `SELECT * FROM logout INNER JOIN items ON itemid = id` and check those row counts.

Comment: check @darshan answer. Guess I'm a bit overworked as I was not able to see that little needle in the haystack. ty anyway !